# get data of given time range in python when time stamp is not proper

Tags: python, pandas

```
        time          a      b
2021-05-23 22:06:54 10.4    70.1    
2021-05-23 22:21:41 10.7    68.3    
2021-05-23 22:36:28 10.4    69.4    
2021-05-23 22:51:15 9.9     71.7    
2021-05-23 23:06:02 9.5     73.1    
... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-11-19 08:18:31 19.8    43.0    
2021-11-19 08:20:04 21.0    42.0    
2021-11-19 08:21:25 35.5    20.0    
2021-11-19 08:21:32 19.8    43.0    
2021-11-19 08:23:05 21.0    42.0
```

here `time` is in the index, not a column.
when I did `df.between_time("2021-11-17 08:15:00","2021-11-19 08:00:00")`
it throws the error `ValueError: Cannot convert arg ['2021-11-17 08:15:00'] to a time`

data frame has not proper time stamp.
What i want to do,-: when i pass time range or date range, i want to get all the data between given time.

Thanks

Comment: AFAICT, `between_time` is used specific for time, i.e. `HH:MM:SS`. You might want `between`, e.g. `df.index.between(start, end)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'between'` this is the error i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`truncate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html):

```
>>> df.truncate("2021-05-23 23:00:00", "2021-11-19 08:20:00")
                        a     b
time                           
2021-05-23 23:06:02   9.5  73.1
2021-11-19 08:18:31  19.8  43.0
```